# Problem with cache asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

VS2005, ASP.NET, C#, IIS6

Hello friends,
  I have a master page divided into three sections i.e. header, details, footer.

The header section contains web user control having AJAX tab container. We are showing or hiding tabs according to user previleges. Initially only one tab is active showing user to log in. When the user logs in other tabs are activated.

I have used <%@ OutputCache Duration="120" VaryByParam="none" %> within my user control. When the user logs in NullReferenceException is generated on one of the method within that control.

When I remove the OutputCache, everything works fine.

Could someone guide me what should i do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing the error?  Otherwise it's difficult to know what the problem is.

Comment: Its generating error on object of that web user control.

Comment: What does that control do? Why you think it has to do with the caching? Maybe you can provide a bit more details/sample about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please visit http://ivautoinc.com. I want to cache the header so that it will not loaded each time when i visit new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "easy" way to fix this is to check if the value is null, if it is null create it.

A better way would be to find out why it is null.

One possibility is that the first time that page is called there is a parameter that determines that one of the controlls should not be created. The second time it is called it is called with a parameter that say that the controll is required, but it is using a cached version of the page that does not have that controll.

Comment: But if i remove the OutputCache statement then it works fine.